# Silverlight override authentication request

Tags: silverlight, authentication, wcf-ria-services

I want to provide a hard coded user name and password in my silveright app so that even when the halfwit users of my software go and do something halfwitted like deleting all users there is still a way to login to the app. So I am looking for some way to intercept the authentication request. Is there some method in AuthenticationBase that can be overriden to do this (nothing obvious that I could see)? Or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override AuthenticationBase.ValidateUser.

Comment: Thanks, works great. PS: I've been reading through your authorisation blog series. Very good stuff, I've learnt a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the AuthenticationService Login method, check for the hard coded pw first, if that fails do the other method.